# .obj/.mtl export, bump map + bump multiplier (`-bm 1.000000`)

Tags: materials, export, normal-map, obj

In an exported .mtl file, after defining a normal map for one of my materials, I get this:

`map_Bump -bm 1.000000 brickwall_normalmap_128.png`

The `-bm` option AFAIK is a (sort of?) standard, sort of non-standard optional thing which is supposed to communicate that all of the normals/bump values in the map should be multiplied with this value, hence 'bump multiply'.

Problem is, I have an application that uses a library to load .obj/.mtl and fails to parse the 'bump multiply' part of the bump map line. Is there any way in blender to stop this 'bump multiply' from being written out at all?

Comment: Are you using the new (non-legacy) exporter? A Normal Map node? Setting the Strength socket to zero appears to make it omit the -bm (even though that isn't correct).

Comment: I am using the newer exporter and a normal map node yeah, on version 3.3.0. That's good to know that there's a way to get rid of it, even if that's pretty hacky. You would expect a strength value of 0 to write out `-bm 0.000000`, probably, right? 

Weird.

Comment: Well the Strength isn't actually a multiplier like bm. Strength=0 makes the Normal Node do nothing so it should really make it omit the map_Bump. But I think map_Bump is also supposed to be a bump map and not a normal map in the first place sooo..... lol